# Can't get Heroku Temporize to accept querystring parameter

Tags: heroku, query-string

I successfully got Temporize (scheduler for Heroku) working. It basically triggers a url in the format: http://my.hostname.com/rest/api?x=param

I later tried adding a bit of extra security, so instead of x=param, I have

x=a_url_encoded_string_which_is_fairly_long_but_not_more_than_240_chars

this generates an error, and like I said, it's only 240chars.

Any ideas on how to get around this?